# To answer indirect question starting with "Whether" using "Yes" or "No"

Tags: questions, programming, technical, tech-writing, indirect-question

I have a technical document with the following table:

(A comparison table of the functions that are used to search for and replace strings.)

```
                | Whether the search is case-sensitive
------------------------------------------------------
RegExReplace()  | It depends on the i) option.
StringReplace() | It depends on the third argument of a function call.
SubStr()        | No.
Trim()          | Yes, always.
```

Is it correct to use "Yes" and "No" in such a case? (The last two rows of the table.)

Since "Whether the search is case-sensitive" is indirect question (or maybe it's not even question at all?), I'm not sure that using "Yes" and "No" is permitted here.

A possible workaround is to change the column header to "If the search is case-sensitive?". It seems it will resolve the issue, but I would prefer to keep "whether".

Comment: This is a technical question, not one about English.  Without further info I have no idea what the options mean.

Comment: Why not, "Is the search case-sensitive?"

Comment: @RamPillai This is because of Microsoft style guide for technical writing: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/style-guide/a-z-word-list-term-collections/i/if-vs-whether-vs-when

Comment: Yes, in case you have to choose between IF or WHETHER only.  The option "Is the search case-sensitive?" has the scope of being answered similarly.

Comment: @RamPillai My bad. I simply misread your first comment.

Comment: Using *Whether* is unheard of in my years writing and editing IT procedures. It sets up your challenging question by causing the problem itself. If column 2 displays whether that function's search string is case-sensitive, its title can be as simple and techie as *Case-Sensitive Search?*. Column 1 needs a title, perhaps Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A technical question, but we use English to control technology so it deserves an answer.

The heading could be profitably put in question form: "Is the search case-sensitive?"

If searching a string for a substring it seems sensible to ignore case (by default, at least), so the answer *No* is appropriate.

If trimming a string it seems likely that the search will be influenced by capitals and proper names, so checking case is a sensible default (to find *Major Brown* but not *major brown*). So *Yes* is appropriate; there is no need for *always*.

You are only asking about the last two rows, However, I note incidentally that the second row might be improved by saying which function requires the third argument. I assume it is the StringReplace() function; if so why not say so? Something like "*determined by the third argument*"